# Workaround for using aggregate function in WHERE for an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I am adding a new feature to a project that uses a PostgreSQL database.

There is a table in the database called `brew_sessions` - this has a column called `condition_date`.

`brew_sessions` is connected to a `recipes` table through `brew_sessions.recipe_id = recipes.id`. `recipes` is then connected to another table called `recipe_fermentation_steps` through `recipes.id = recipe_fermentation_steps.recipe_id`.

I am wanting to run an update statement to set the `status` field on the `brew_sessions` field to 30 when the `condition_date` is less than or equal to a calculated number of days from the `condition_date` value.

This value is the sum of `recipe_fermentation_steps.time`.

For example:

```
SELECT
  brew_sessions.id,
  SUM(recipe_fermentation_steps.time)
FROM brew_sessions
  INNER JOIN recipes ON brew_sessions.recipe_id = recipes.id
  INNER JOIN recipe_fermentation_steps ON recipes.id = recipe_fermentation_steps.recipe_id
GROUP BY brew_sessions.id
```

This has led me to the below query:

```
UPDATE brew_sessions
SET status = 30 FROM recipes
  INNER JOIN recipe_fermentation_steps ON recipes.id = recipe_fermentation_steps.recipe_id
WHERE brew_sessions.recipe_id = recipes.id
AND brew_sessions.condition_date
    <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day' * SUM(recipe_fermentation_steps.time)
```

However, this doesn't run as you cannot use an aggregate function in a `WHERE`.

How do I write the above correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **subquery**. Like:

```
UPDATE brew_sessions b
SET    status = 30
FROM  (
   SELECT recipe_id, SUM(time) AS sum_time
   FROM   recipe_fermentation_steps
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) f
WHERE  b.recipe_id = f.recipe_id
AND    b.condition_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day' * f.sum_time;
```

If referential integrity is enforced with FK constraints, you do not need to involve the table `recipes` at all.

The approach is questionable, though. Typically, you do not write functionally dependent values or values depending on the current time into tables. Use a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) (or [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)) or similar for that.

Comment: This was a great help - I realised I had made a typo in my question. `condition_date` does not need to be compared against itself including the time intervals, it needed to be tested against the current time, minus the time intervals. Thank you a lot for helping!

Comment: Very good. But If the value also depends on the current time, a *view* would look even better, yet.

Comment: This is just a once-off update I need to run. It is set appropriately going forward, i just needed a way to historically update records.